# typescript: Getting Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a react app using typescript. In one of the sections, I need to combine a set of default users with negative userIds with other users returned by `getUsers(orgId)` api. Code is below:

```
   ....
   const [assignedUserOptions, setAssignedUserOptions] = useState([]);   

   const getUsersAsync = async () => {
    const defaultUsers = [
      { value: "-1", label: "Developer" },
      { value: "-2", label: "Quality Analyst" },
      { value: "-3", label: "Senior Developer" },
      { value: "-4", label: "Senior Quality Analyst" },
      { value: "-5", label: "Manager" },
      { value: "-6", label: "Director" },
      { value: "-7", label: "SVP" },
      { value: "-8", label: "Support" },
    ];

    // getUsers Api call which returns an array of object like 
    /*
    [
      {
        "userId": "https://userapi.mydomain.com/employee/id/1",
        "orgId": 1,
        "firstName": "Jeff",
        "lastName": "Smith"
      }
    ]
    */
    await getUsers(orgId).then((response) => {
      if (response) {
        const assignedToOptions = response.map(
          (x: { userId: string; firstName: string; lastName: string }) => ({
            value: x.userId.substring(x.userId.lastIndexOf("/") + 1),
            label: `${x.firstName} ${x.lastName}`,
          })
        );

        setAssignedUserOptions([...defaultUsers, ...assignedToOptions]); // warning here
      }
    });
  };
  ...
```

I get a warning as below.

```
Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
    Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

My company policy is to keep the `"strict": true` in tsconfig.json. I see the defaultUsers is showing up as `{value: string; label: string;}[]` and `assignedToOptions as any`. How can I fix the arrays to make the spread operator to work?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not pass a generic parameter explicitly, this empty array is inferred as `never[]`:

```
const [assignedUserOptions, setAssignedUserOptions] = useState([]);
```

The fix is simple: just add a generic parameter:

```
const [assignedUserOptions, setAssignedUserOptions] = useState<{ value: string; label: string }>([]);
```

Comment: Thank you! But after I made that change, I am getting `Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ value: string; label: string; } | (() => { value: string; label: string; })'.ts(2345)` on that line.